# Can't run Grunt command in terminal - gets stuck at SASS

Tags: terminal, sass, gruntjs

I'm getting  a strange error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:12: uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError)
```

Anyone have any advice? I think it might be a PATH issue, just not sure how to reset it!

Here is the error message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:12: uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/ext.rb:13
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1431:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1430:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tmpdir.rb:14
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/util.rb:881:in `atomic_create_and_write_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/filesystem.rb:39:in `_store'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/base.rb:51:in `store'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `store'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `store'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:353:in `_to_tree'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:349:in `process_result'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/../lib/sass/../sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.12/bin/sass:9
    from /usr/bin/sass:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/sass:19
```

Comment: Same here, on trying any of the gem commands (gem list / update etc), I get a similar error: /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:40: uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like some problems with updating.

you can try to update:

```
gem update --system
gem update sass
```

Comment: Those commands aren't working - just getting an error message. Not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what the cause is, but I think a recent gem update broke it for me (since some rubygems versions shipped with issues: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/UPGRADING.rdoc).

What fixed it for me was manually downloading and installing rubygems from http://rubygems.org/pages/download. Give it a try, might fix your issue as well, while we wait for someone to explain the root cause.